# ORACLE EXIST (Subquery)

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

From what I learned, SQL EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered to be met, if the subquery returns at least one row.

Then why do these code give different results?

```
/* #1 */
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE employees.department_id= 20);

/* #2 */
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM departments
WHERE employees.department_id= 20);
```

I would imagine if any of the subqueries return any rows they evaluate TRUE. Therefore, the outer query will return all rows from the employee tables.

However, only the #1 code returns all rows from the employee table. #2 returns ros that have department_id=20.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Neither of those statements really make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is your first query:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM employees e2
              WHERE e2.department_id = 20
             );
```

In this query, the inner `WHERE` is referring to the inner table.  So one of two things can happen:

- `employees` has an employee in that department.  In that case, all employees are returned in the outer query.
- `employees` has no employees in that department.  In that case, no employees are returned in the outer query.

This is all-or-thing.

The second query is:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM departments d
              WHERE e.department_id = 20
             );
```

The inner reference is to the outer query.  For each row in `employees`, the query goes and looks to see if the subquery returns any rows.  If it does, then the row is returned.

The subquery will return either all rows from `departments` (if the employee in the outer query has `department_id = 20`) or no rows.  So, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE e.department_id = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Query 2 should be :

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT * FROM departments
             WHERE departments.department_id= 20)
```

You're using employees alias, so when the employee department_id is different then `20` , the subquery returns no rows, regardless the fact that the condition is inside the subquery and not in the outer query .

Comment: That doesn't really makes sense. It says "*return all employees if there is (at least) one department with the id = 20 - but I don't care if there are any employees assigned to that department*". So if there is no department with that ID the query would return nothing, even if there are many employees

Comment: Agreed ,  makes no sense at all , but seems like op was just trying to understand Exists

Answer (score 0):

The keypart is incorrect qualified name:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM departments
WHERE employees.department_id= 20);
      -- here should be departments.department_id
```

You are referring to column from outer query. What you want is:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM departments
WHERE departments.department_id= 20);
```